# Is calling session_write_close necessary?

Tags: php, session

When a PHP script exits, is the equivalent of session_write_close called or does one need to call it explicitly? What about if a script exits because of an `exit` call or some error?

Answer (score 3):

Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php